# Can you run SAS drive from SAS backplane to SATA on mobo?

Tags: hard-drive, sas, sata

Have an SAS drive plugged into SAS port on the backplane, and it is connected to SATA on the motherboard. Is it possible to use it this way? It is a testing server for cloning another SSD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that won't work. SATA controllers don't speak SAS nor do SAS drives speak SATA.

You can connect SATA drives to (most) SAS controllers, but not vice versa.

SAS drives also require a SAS backplane, they won't fit into a SATA backplane mechanically.

Comment: It's not a SATA backplane, it is a SAS backplane that is connected to MOBO over sata. To clarify, will this setup work or no?

Comment: A SAS backplane is not a problem - SAS drives won't fit a SATA backplane - the SATA controller is.